# Discord Formatting in "Code Blocks" box problem

Tags: discord

I would like to format the text in my discord bot's message, but unfortunately it doesn't work:

````
var string = "```Questionnaire\n${topic}```";
````

${topic} - can't topic, but only it works:
    var string = `Questionnaire\n${topic}`;

My problem is that i can't enter the text into the table, i want to get topic in box (```)

````
var string = "```Questionnaire\n${topic}```"; // this don't work
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
 var topic = "in the box";

 var string = `\`\`\`
    Questionnaire
    ${topic}
\`\`\``;
```